# Increase stroke width of line drawn using PathDashPathEffect

Tags: android

[image]

Last line in the image is drawn using PathDashPathEffect. I used the following code to draw this line.

```
mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        //      mPaint.setAlpha(120);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);

        cornerpatheffect = new CornerPathEffect(10);
        pathdashpath = new PathDashPathEffect(makePathDash(), 10, 3,
                PathDashPathEffect.Style.MORPH);
        patheffect = new ComposePathEffect(cornerpatheffect, pathdashpath);
        mPaint.setPathEffect(pathdashpath);


private Path makePathDash() {
        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(-6, 9/2);
        p.lineTo(6,9/2);
        p.lineTo(6,9/2-1);
        p.lineTo(-6, 9/2-1);
        p.close();
        p.moveTo(-6, -(9/2));
        p.lineTo(6,-(9/2));
        p.lineTo(6, -(9/2-1));
        p.lineTo(-6, -(9/2-1));
        return p;
    }
```

Is there any way to increase the stroke width of both lines. For your information, setstrokewidth method doesn't with PathDashPathEffect. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer,

yes you just have to change the coordinates like this:

```
private Path makePathDash() {
        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(-6, 9/2);
        p.lineTo(6,9/2);
        p.lineTo(6,9/2-2);
        p.lineTo(-6, 9/2-2);
        p.close();
        p.moveTo(-6, -(9/2));
        p.lineTo(6,-(9/2));
        p.lineTo(6, -(9/2-2));
        p.lineTo(-6, -(9/2-2));
        return p;
    }
```

and change (-2) to (-3) to have thicker ...